# SQL Query to return last messages

Tags: sql

Example:

[image: Msg]

I hope you understand.
I'm trying with this query, but it returns only those that were sent by user 1. I also need those that were sent to him. But without repeating the same participants.

Comment: Which RDBMS (MySQL, SQLServer, Oracle, etc) is this?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT idMsg(Max), idFrom, idTo
FROM Messages
WHERE idFrom = 1 OR idTo = 1
GROUP BY idFrom
ORDER BY visualized DESC
```

or

```
SELECT top 1 idMsg, idFrom, idTo
FROM Messages
WHERE idFrom = 1 OR idTo = 1
ORDER BY DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:
`SELECT idMsg, idFrom, idTo
FROM Messages
WHERE idFrom = 1 OR idTo = 1
GROUP BY idFrom
ORDER BY visualized DESC`

Comment: I already tried something like this, however it returns all messages that involve the user.

I just want the last message he had with the user.

I tried:


select idFrom, idTo, idMsg from mensagens

      where idMsg IN (select max(idMsg) 
      
      from mensagens a
      
      where idTo='1'
      
      group by idFrom)
      
      ORDER BY dataMsg DESC LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0

It almost works, but also precisoq u return the message sent to the user 1 user 2

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like

```
SELECT MAX(id), idto, idfrom
FROM messages
WHERE idto = 1 OR idfrom = 1
GROUP BY idto, idfrom
```

Its probably a little more than you need, but its nice and clear.

Comment: This will repeat user pairs where the same user is in different id fields - eg: if you had `id` 8 `idfrom` 6 `idto` 1 and `id` 9 `idfrom` 1 `idto` 6, then you would see results for both `id` 8 and `id` 9.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select case when idfrom < idto then idfrom else idto end userid1,
       case when idfrom > idto then idfrom else idto end userid2,
       max(id) id
from messages
where 1 in (idfrom, idto)
group by
       case when idfrom < idto then idfrom else idto end,
       case when idfrom > idto then idfrom else idto end
```

Answer (score 0):

Query:

```
SELECT m1.idMsg, m1.idFrom, m1.idTo
FROM Messages m1
WHERE m1.dataMsg = (SELECT MAX(m2.dataMsg)
                    FROM Messages m2
                    WHERE m2.idFrom = m1.idFrom
                    AND m2.idTo = m1.idTo)
```